# Fairness of socket write() in 2 parallel connections?

Tags: linux, multithreading, sockets, io, network-protocols

Suppose I have a multi-threaded program in which each of the 2 threads:

- has its own socket `socket_fd` in default (blocking) mode
- repeatedly sends data using the `write(socket_fd, data, data_len)` such that network becomes a bottleneck
- the size of the data being passed to `write` (i.e. `data_len`) is always equal to MSS; for simplicity, assume `data_len = 500`

I'm wondering about the fairness of writes assuming a single network interface card, i.e.:  if thread 2 calls write 9x less frequently, is there a weak guarantee that the data sent by thread 2 will be roughly `1/(1 + 9)` of the total data sent *within reasonable time* (i.e. thread 2 will eventually send its data even though thread 1 keeps the underlying media very busy by constantly sending excessive amount of data)?

I am primarily interested in the case where thread 1 (which sends more data) uses TCP and thread 2 uses DCCP. Nevertheless, answers for the scenarios in which thread 2 uses UDP and TCP are also welcome.

Comment: I think you might want to use `send()` (possibly with `flags`).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the [queuing discipline](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Traffic-Control-HOWTO/classless-qdiscs.html) which schedules outgoing packets on the network interface. The default [pfifo_fast, the default Linux qdisc](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Traffic-Control-HOWTO/classless-qdiscs.html#qs-pfifo_fast) organizes outgoing packets into fifo queues indexed by ToS field. Outgoing packets with the same ToS are sent in the order the kernel receives packets from applications.

Comment: Are you saying that all these packets go into the same FIFO queue, regardless of the protocol they use? Also, do they share the same outgoing packet buffer with respect to the transport protocol used?

Comment: @leden They go to same ToS queue regardless of protocol.

Comment: @leden Not sure which packet buffer you mean. Each packet is written into its own [socket buffer](http://vger.kernel.org/~davem/skb.html), buffers are linked into a list. The queueing discipline maintains a list of those buffers.

Comment: ^: A call to write() copies from a buffer in user space (`data`) to some buffer in kernel space. Are you saying that a TCP socket has its own send queue that is different from the one used by a UDP/DCCP socket for the second connection? If so, would 2 TCP connections still share the same send queue?

Comment: @leden Nope, that is far from what i said.

Comment: @leden: (simplified version) each write() copies data to a new socket buffer. Each TCP socket has its own retransmit queue, which points to some skbuffs. When skbuffs are (re-)transmitted by TCP, they are cloned, have headers added, and are put into qdiscs, to be eventually transmitted by the device. When the ACK arrives, the original skbuff is removed from the retransmit queue and freed.

Comment: @ninjalj: So, if there are multiple retransmit queues, does it mean that `write()` on a TCP socket actually blocks until retransmit queue becomes non-full and `data` is copied to it? But this doesn't make much sense to me because for UDP there is no need for retransmission queue, which would mean write() would need to wait until - but can you tell easily once a packet leaves qdisc queue and is actually sent over the network?

Comment: @leden: socket memory is uncharged every time a socket buffer is destroyed. On TCP there is the original skbuff at the retransmit queue and a clone of it sent to the device (to the qdisc at the device). Clones have a NULL destructor, since they share data with their original skbuff.